# How to AJAX to HTTP request JSON to pre-populate a web form?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, http, playframework

Okay, using Scala Play Framework I have an Action method in my Application Controller that accesses a database for a specific serial and sends a JSON object using Ok(json), which can be accessed through the route `GET /json/:serial controllers.Application.getData(serial: String)`. This part works; I am able to retrieve a unformatted JSON objects for specific serial numbers going directly through localhost/json/*serial#*.

In my views, there is a page for editing this database information. There is an HTML select drop down with a list of serial numbers, and when one of them is selected I'd like to send an AJAX request with that serial number to /json/### and get a JSON object in return. Once I have the JSON object, the forms should be populated with that information so the users know what they are editing.

So essentially my question is how can I use AJAX/jQuery to request a JSON object over HTTP (using route /json/:serial) so that I can populate an HTML form with the various fields in the JSON object when a serial is selected from a drop down?

Let me know if anything is unclear or too ambiguous! Thanks

EDIT: Some Code:

```
val getData(serial: String) = Action {

val scInfo = *some database query*
val ctrlInfo = *another database query*
val json: JsValue = Json.obj(
        "name" -> scInfo(0)._1,
        "notes" -> scInfo(0)._2,
        "ctrl1" -> Json.obj("name" -> scInfo(0)._3,
            "port" -> scInfo(0)._4,
            "apc" -> scInfo(0)._5),
        "ctrl2" -> Json.obj("name" -> ctrlInfo(0)._1,
            "port" -> ctrlInfo(0)._2,
            "apc" -> ctrlInfo(0)._3),
        "rack" -> scInfo(0)._6,
        "comtrol" -> scInfo(0)._7
    )

    Ok(json)
}
```

This is a picture of what the form will roughly look like (I figured seeing the actual page was easier than reading the markup)

[image: Form]

So when a Storage Center is selected, that number is sent via AJAX to `/json/:serial` and should request a JSON object as a result, which will then populate the other fields in the form.

EDIT 2:

Here's the markup for the view. It's using the Play template engine so anything with a `@` in front of it is just scala-code generating markup.

```
<div class="header-wrapper">
        <h2 class="header">Edit Information for...</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="sc-content">
    <form class="form-horizontal col-md-12" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputSC" class="control-label">Storage Center</label><br>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select class="form-control" onfocus="this.blur()" id="inputSC" placeholder=" ">
                    @storageCenters.map { sc =>
                    <option id="selectSC@sc._1">@{sc._1.replace('-', '/')}</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputRack" class="control-label">Rack</label><br>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select class="form-control" onfocus="this.blur()" id="inputRack" placeholder=" ">
                    @racks.map { rack =>
                    <option id="selectRack@rack.name">@rack.name</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputConsoleIP" class="control-label">Console IP/Port</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputConsoleIP" placeholder="i.e. 127.0.0.1">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPort" placeholder="i.e. 00000">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputAPC" class="control-label">APC Outlet</label><br>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAPC" placeholder="i.e. 12">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputNotes" class="control-label">Notes</label><br>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputNotes" value="Default">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div style="margin-lefT:4%;">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit Changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: show code in question, currently this is just a vague question.

Comment: @abc123 I added the controller method and a picture of the form after rendering the markup

Comment: Ah, this question is really quiet simple.  Are you using `knockout.js`? And finally can you edit the front end(client side) code? because if you can you are simply talking about a `.change` event binding in `jquery` and then an `ajax` call that on `success` fills out the form.

Comment: Seeing the real frontend markup is more helpful that the image but keep both if you can provide the markup

Comment: @abc123 Yes this should be simple, I just couldn't find any good examples/explanations online and I'm fairly new to web development. I just made another edit with the front end markup, but no I am not using knockout.js, just bootstrap framework (both css and js) along with some custom scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A friend helped me out and I was able to come up with an answer! It was simple using jQuery as anticipated.

*Front-End:*

The only thing that changed was the HTML select tag gained an `onchange="fillForm()"` attribute which would call a JS function anytime a serial number was selected.

```
<select class="form-control" onfocus="this.blur()" id="inputSC" onchange="fillForm()">
```

*Back-End:*

I created a JS file with several functions pertaining to this form but in particular the `fillForm()` function.

```
function fillForm() {
    var val = $('#inputSC').val() // selected value
    val = val.replace('/', '-');
    $.getJSON('/json/' + val, function (data) {
        //printJSON(data);
        $('#inputRack').val(data.rack);
        $('#inputNotes').val(data.notes);
        $('#inputComtrol').text(data.comtrol);
        $('#inputPort').val(data.ctrl1.port);
        $('#inputAPC').val(data.ctrl1.apc);
    });
}
```

And for those who are not very good with JavaScript/jQuery, this function first retrieves the value of the drop-down select tag *(note that selecting a new value from the drop-down on the page triggers this function)* and then formats the string *(something specific to my application)*. Then using jQuery, it calls `$.getJSON(url [, data] [,success]);` [(here's the documentation)](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) to retrieve the serial-specific JSON from the URL I had already set up in my routes, and then changes the values of each of the fields in the form to the data from the JSON. In my opinion, it's easier to think of the `$.getJSON` signature as `$.getJSON(url, callback);`, but refer to the documentation for official knowledge.

**It worked!**

Feel free to comment with questions that I will attempt to answer!